# View Body not showing in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, servlets

I'm currently trying to get into Java Web Development in general in Spring more specifically.

I've set up my project as follows -

hello.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>ABC ${message}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldController.java:

```
package controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

I can start up the Server just fine and navigate to hello.html, which is resolved by the servlet to give me hello.jsp, the title of the .jsp shows (Spring 3.0 MVC Series: etc. etc.), alas, the body does not. Not the JSTL-Variable and not the "ABC" either.

I've implemented jstl-1.2 in my lib-folder.

Comment: is there any exception on the console ?

Comment: No, there is no exception showing on the console. Also my System.out.println is being shown just as it should.

Comment: How are you building/deploying this project? I've used your exact code built with Maven on the command line and am seeing the message as expected.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and its integrated Server plugin to publish it to my local tomcat.

Comment: OK I'm using Jetty and Maven command line. I'll try Tomcat instead but doubt that's the problem **Edit:** Working in Tomcat 7 for me also

Comment: So the view is resolved correctly but the `<body>` is not output? Very strange. What browser are you using to view the page and can you look at the page source to see what the complete markup is please?

Comment: the <body> itself is being shown, just not it's contents. it's like <body></body> ... not the <p> either.

Comment: If you remove ${message} do you see the ABC? Also, have you checked that the correct HTML output is being sent from the server? Don't just look at the dom in say, Chrome, as modern browsers often add missing elements for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

change to the above
Also, my viewResolver is different to yrs :

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick, the servlet is being called, the controller does what it's supposed to do, the sysout shows on the console and I'm redirected to my view, where I see the page title but not the content of the body.

Comment: the jsp is not being processed, access it via /hello with out the html extension

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same effect if I call it via `http://localhost:8081/SpringTest/hello` - title shows, body doesn't.

Comment: do you get the paragraph abc ?

Comment: what does your console say  - output from the server ?

Comment: Wait, there is - this:

`INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
22.06.2012 10:57:24 org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler`

Comment: @DennisRöttger your index.jsp is not the same as your hello.jsp is it ? And try updating yr viewResolver

Comment: No, it isn't. My index.jsp looks like this: 

`<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>`

(and its body shows just fine)

Comment: I would also remove the html extension, that may be causign the problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your jsp file. Please try to put the following line as first line in your hello.jsp file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

**UPDATE**

Try to use **InternalResourceViewResolver** class in viewResolver bean instead of **UrlBasedViewResolver**.

According to me that should resolve your problem. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the trick either, it works just as "well" as before, but no change, JSTL variable isn't shown, "ABC" isn't shown either, just an empty body.

Comment: Where have you put your hello.jsp file??

Comment: WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

Comment: I think I have got your problem. See the update in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you included taglibs in jsp header as

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
```